# String representation of byte array

Tags: c#, string, byte, arrays

I have a string that represents a byte

```
string s = "\x00af";
```

I write this string to a file so the file contains the literal "\x00af" and not the byte it represents, later I read this string from the file, how can I now treat this string as byte again (and not the literal)?

Here is a sample code:

```
public static void StringAndBytes()
{
    string s = "\x00af";
    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

    // Length would be 1
    Console.WriteLine(b.Length);

    // Write this to a file as literal
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\MyTry.txt");
    sw.WriteLine("\\x00af");
    sw.Close();

    // Read it from the file
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\MyTry.txt");
    s = sr.ReadLine();
    sr.Close();

    // Get the bytes and Length would be 6, as it treat the string as string
    // and not the byte it represents
    b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    Console.WriteLine(b.Length);
}
```

Any idea on how I convert the string from being a text to the string representing a byte?  Thx!

Comment: Don't write it like that.  You don't want to have to write a C# compiler to read it back.  And never store bytes in a string, not all byte values are legal Unicode characters.  Use Convert.ToBase64String to encode byte[] into a string that you can easily write to a text file.

Comment: When questions are answer you can mark them as such ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a requirement for the file content to have the string literal? If no, then you might want to write the `byte[] b` array directly to the file. That way when you read it, it is exactly, what you wrote.

```
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(s);
File.WriteAllBytes ("c:\\temp\\MyTry.txt", b);

b = File.ReadAllBytes ("c:\\temp\\MyTry.txt");
s = Encoding.UTF32.GetString (b);
```

If you need the file content to have the string literal, while being able to convert it to the original text written, you will have to choose the right encoding. I believe UTF32 to be the best.

```
    b = new byte[4];
    b[0] = Byte.Parse(s.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    string v = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(b);
    string w = "\x00af";

    if (v != w)
        MessageBox.Show("Diff [" + w + "] = [" + v + "] ");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Same");
```

Comment: Thank you! your second example was exactly what I wanted. The file have to have the literal (what Im doing actually is parsing .cs files looking for those special strings and manipulate them).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you're not writing the string `s` to the file. You have an extra `\` in your `WriteLine` statement! `WriteLine("\\x00af")` writes the characters `\`, `x`, `0`, `0`, `a` and `f`, since the first `\` acts as an escape to the second one ...

Did you mean

```
sw.WriteLine("\x00af");
```

or

```
sw.WriteLine(s);
```

instead? This works as expected in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byte[])` method. It is also available from all the others encoding. Make sure you always use the same encoding to decode the byte[] as you used to encode it or you won't get the same value every time.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx)'s an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse a string representing each byte:

```
Byte b = Byte.Parse(s);
```

Comment: Yes, but doesn't parse "\x00af".